# Uploading of workitems from excel to vso along with attachments in bulk

Tags: excel, tfs, azure-devops

Is there a way to upload the workitems from excel along with an attachment to each workitem in bulk to VSO

Comment: You should describe the problem more and provide some example code of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess he was following this guide, no coding involved: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't bulk attach files with the workitems from excel, it can be achieved by REST API. Here is sample for you https://gist.github.com/kshuma/7487393.